# MVC with windows authentication is prompting on all actions, not just ones marked with [Authorize]

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication, basic-authentication

I need to use Windows authentication on an MVC project, and only validate on a couple of actions. Currently, I am being prompted on every action, even ones without `[Authorize]`.
I have these in my web.config...

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />
<add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>
```

And in my project properties, I have Anonymous Authentication=Disabled, and Windows Authentication=Enabled. And I don't have `[Authorize]` on any controllers, just a couple of actions. Those actions seem to be authorizing correctly, but my other ones are prompting too. I've tried `[AllowAnonymous]` on my other actions also, but that didn't work. Am I missing something, is there a way to only prompt on the actions I mark, and not on others? I'm just testing with IIS Express right now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need Anonymous Authentication enabled if you're only going to want to authenticate only some of your actions. Without that enabled, there's no other way for a user that isn't authenticated to view the webpages.